# is there any other Base64 type encryption and decryption in php?

Tags: php

is there any other Base64 type encryption and decryption in php ?

The problem is that base 64 give a longer value and increases the size of the data whereas i'm looking for something to reduce the size of the data.

is there any ?

Comment: Base64 isn't encryption, it's encoding. If you want to reduce the size of data, then use gzip or zip libraries. It's not encoding, but archiving. Whenever you encode or encrypt something, you usually get much larger data set. You can't encrypt and shrink something just like that.

Answer (score 5):

- base64 is not an encryption but an encoding
- pick an encryption algorithm from http://docs.php.net/mcrypt, see also http://docs.php.net/refs.crypto
- to (possibly) reduce the size use a data compression algorithm, see also http://docs.php.net/refs.compression

Answer (score 0):

Base64 isn't so much encrypting and encoding - anyone can return a base64 encoded file/string into the original.

If you want to reduce the data size, try compressing it using for instance http://php.net/zip. If you still need to send the the data to another system, you could then base64 encode the resulting compressed data.

Do you actually want to encrypt the content (a security measure) or just make it viable for transmission inside for instance an XML or JSON stream, or is compression your only concern?

Comment: what do you want to do with the data? send it to another server? store it in a Database? store it in a file?